# Drawing birth and death process diagram with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw birth  and death process diagram under queuing theory with text on top and bottom of the diagram. I am using TikzEdt software. When I compile the code I received an error  message as:

```
'Couldn't parse code. MismatchedTokenException: Expected token '}'. Instead found "1." which is of type FLOAT_WO_EXP in line 17 at position 125.
Couldn't parse code. MismatchedTokenException: Expected token '}'. Instead found "1." which is of type FLOAT_WO_EXP in line 17 at position 125.
Compilation failed with exit code 1''
```

Also I found it difficult to write under the bottom of the arcs.
I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \draw  (-4.5,4) rectangle (10,-3);

[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
 \clip(-2.84,-1.3) rectangle (9.04,3.58);
 \draw(0.,1.) circle (0.5003998401278722cm);
 \draw(2.,1.) circle (0.46173585522460786cm);
 \draw(4.,1.) circle (0.44045431091090476cm);
 \draw(6.,1.) circle (0.44181444068749043cm);
 \draw(8.,1.) circle (0.44045431091090476cm);
 \draw(-2.,1.) circle (0.523450093132096cm);
 \draw (-2.08,1.14) node[anchor=north west] {0};
 \draw (-0.08,1.16) node[anchor=north west] {1};
 \draw (1.92,1.2) node[anchor=north west] {2};
 \draw (3.76,1.16) node[anchor=north west] {n-1};
 \draw (5.92,1.2) node[anchor=north west] {n};
 \draw (7.5,1.16) node[anchor=north west] {n+1};
 \draw [shift={(-0.9815173101890807,1.5112413590134577)}] plot[domain=-0.011986604704742554:3.1296060488850506,variable=\t]({1.*1.018555861321933*cos(\t r)+0.*1.018555861321933*sin(\t r)},{0.*1.018555861321933*cos(\t r)+1.*1.018555861321933*sin(\t r)});
 \draw [shift={(1.0368933040163526,1.4796489900153262)}] plot[domain=-0.019382604449061702:3.1222100491407314,variable=\t]({1.*1.000115782939687*cos(\t r)+0.*1.000115782939687*sin(\t r)},{0.*1.000115782939687*cos(\t r)+1.*1.000115782939687*sin(\t r)});
 \draw [shift={(3.0184106142054334,1.4503598330233691)},line width=2.pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]  plot[domain=-0.010090966788127709:3.131501686801665,variable=\t]({1.*0.9816393643659953*cos(\t r)+0.*0.9816393643659953*sin(\t r)},{0.*0.9816393643659953*cos(\t r)+1.*0.9816393643659953*sin(\t r)});
 \draw [shift={(4.990803512086236,1.4409428653857879)}] plot[domain=4.930891234521944E-4:3.1420857427132454,variable=\t]({1.*0.9908036325366876*cos(\t r)+0.*0.9908036325366876*sin(\t r)},{0.*0.9908036325366876*cos(\t r)+1.*0.9908036325366876*sin(\t r)});
 \draw [shift={(6.999605559480942,1.4407668947979961)}] plot[domain=-6.527759571728353E-4:3.1409398776326203,variable=\t]({1.*1.0179987522014697*cos(\t r)+0.*1.0179987522014697*sin(\t r)},{0.*1.0179987522014697*cos(\t r)+1.*1.0179987522014697*sin(\t r)});
 \draw [shift={(6.980403063500899,0.559301340676507)}] plot[domain=-3.1409328928241607:6.597607656324556E-4,variable=\t]({1.*1.0004650415559373*cos(\t r)+0.*1.0004650415559373*sin(\t r)},{0.*1.0004650415559373*cos(\t r)+1.*1.0004650415559373*sin(\t r)});
 \draw [shift={(4.98996911984415,0.5590934811158415)}] plot[domain=3.1411358636427766:6.28272851723257,variable=\t]({1.*0.9899692231261799*cos(\t r)+0.*0.9899692231261799*sin(\t r)},{0.*0.9899692231261799*cos(\t r)+1.*0.9899692231261799*sin(\t r)});
 \draw [shift={(2.990388842416927,0.5491050625508038)},line width=2.pt,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt]  plot[domain=-3.131251786904409:0.010340866685384142,variable=\t]({1.*1.0096651406276953*cos(\t r)+0.*1.0096651406276953*sin(\t r)},{0.*1.0096651406276953*cos(\t r)+1.*1.0096651406276953*sin(\t r)});
 \draw [shift={(0.9903888424169273,0.5191322979423201)}] plot[domain=-3.1218735235713657:0.0197191300184274,variable=\t]({1.*0.9905814270424891*cos(\t r)+0.*0.9905814270424891*sin(\t r)},{0.*0.9905814270424891*cos(\t r)+1.*0.9905814270424891*sin(\t r)});
 \draw [shift={(-1.,0.4880750333700159)}] plot[domain=-3.1300680373355956:0.01152461625419754,variable=\t]({1.*1.0000664120651637*cos(\t r)+0.*1.0000664120651637*sin(\t r)},{0.*1.0000664120651637*cos(\t r)+1.*1.0000664120651637*sin(\t r)});
 \draw (-1.24,3) node[anchor=north west] {$\lambda_0$};
 \draw (0.92,3.) node[anchor=north west] {$\lambda_1$};
 \draw (4.74,3.) node[anchor=north west] {$\lambda_{n-1}$};
 \draw (6.84,3.02) node[anchor=north west] {$\lambda_n$};
 \draw (-1.24,-3.5) node[anchor=north west] {$\mu_0$};
  \draw (0.92,-6) node[anchor=north west] {$\2mu$};
  \draw (4.74,-3.) node[anchor=north west] {$\3mu$};
 \draw (6.84,-3.02) node[anchor=north west] {$\4mu$};
\draw (-2.,0.476549906867904)-- (-2.28,0.14);
 \draw (-2.,0.476549906867904)-- (-1.64,0.26);
 \draw (0.,0.4996001598721278)-- (-0.28,0.26);
 \draw (0.,0.4996001598721278)-- (0.28,0.26);
 \draw (1.9807776848338545,0.5386644360125123)-- (1.64,0.28);
 \draw (1.9807776848338545,0.5386644360125123)-- (2.26,0.34);
 \draw (4.,0.5595456890890953)-- (4.3,0.32);
 \draw (4.,0.5595456890890953)-- (3.7,0.36);
 \draw (5.9799382396883,0.5586412731425877)-- (5.66,0.34);
 \draw (5.9799382396883,0.5586412731425877)-- (6.24,0.3);
 \draw (0.03696537962184012,1.4990326248949253)-- (-0.2,1.82);
 \draw (0.03696537962184012,1.4990326248949253)-- (0.42,1.8);
 \draw (2.0369572896787735,1.469470391582537)-- (1.78,1.72);
 \draw (2.0369572896787735,1.469470391582537)-- (2.4,1.72);
 \draw (4.0000498342454085,1.4508921413779512)-- (3.74,1.76);
 \draw (4.0000498342454085,1.4508921413779512)-- (4.42,1.76);
 \draw (5.974507837021575,1.5593389774478226)-- (5.76,1.82);
 \draw (5.974507837021575,1.5593389774478226)-- (6.32,1.74);
 \draw (8.012632698570675,1.5412530876377109)-- (7.78,1.74);
 \draw (8.012632698570675,1.5412530876377109)-- (8.36,1.74);
 \begin{scriptsize}
 \draw[color=black] (3.82,1.14) ;
 \draw[color=black] (-0.02,0.3) ;
 \draw[color=black] (4.,0.36) ;
 \draw[color=black] (6.38,1.6) ;
 \draw[color=black] (8.2,2.12) ;
 \end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Someone should help me as to how the values `\mu`, `2\mu`, `3\mu` and `4\mu` appear at the bottom of the diagram. Thanks so much

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can highlight code using the `{}` in he gui for backticks if it is inline. It is easier to help you if you add a complete  [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: Did you want those `\mu` to be like in my answer or Paul's answer? I'm confused on that.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for?

[image: birth death diagram]

I accidentally trimmed the right edge off when getting the screenshot.

If so you can get it with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
 \draw  (-4.5,4) rectangle (10,-3);
 \clip(-2.84,-1.3) rectangle (9.04,3.58);
 \node (zero) [draw, circle, minimum size=1cm] at (-2,1cm) {$0$};
 \node (one) [draw, circle, minimum size=1cm] at (0,1cm) {$1$};
 \node (two) [draw, circle, minimum size=1cm] at (2,1cm) {$2$};
 \node (enminusone) [draw, circle, minimum size=1cm] at (4,1cm) {$n-1$};
 \node (en) [draw, circle, minimum size=1cm] at (6,1cm) {$n$};
 \node (enplusone) [draw, circle, minimum size=1cm] at (8,1cm) {$n+1$};

 \draw [->] (zero) .. controls +(0,2) and +(0,2) .. node [midway, above] {$\lambda_0$} (one);
 \draw [->] (one) .. controls +(0,2) and +(0,2) .. node [midway, above] {$\lambda_1$} (two);
 \draw [->, very thick, dashed] (two) .. controls +(0,2) and +(0,2) .. (enminusone);
 \draw [->] (enminusone) .. controls +(0,2) and +(0,2) .. node [midway, above] {$\lambda_{n-1}$} (en);
 \draw [->] (en) .. controls +(0,2) and +(0,2) .. node [midway, above] {$\lambda_n$} (enplusone);

 \draw [->] (enplusone) .. controls +(0,-2) and +(0,-2) .. node [midway, below] {$\mu_4$} (en);
 \draw [->] (en) .. controls +(0,-2) and +(0,-2) .. node [midway, below] {$\mu_3$} (enminusone);
 \draw [->, very thick, dashed] (enminusone) .. controls +(0,-2) and +(0,-2) .. (two);
 \draw [->] (two) .. controls +(0,-2) and +(0,-2) .. node [midway, below] {$\mu_2$} (one);
 \draw [->] (one) .. controls +(0,-2) and +(0,-2) .. node [midway, below] {$\mu_0$} (zero);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Notice how I was able to draw, name, and print text inside each circle by making them each a `node`, this permitted the easy creation of the arrows between each node referencing the name of each circle.

This can be improved upon visually by separating the arrows a little bit, this gives more clarity about which line points where. See the below sample:

[image: improved birth death diagram]

The changes appear in the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
 \draw  (-4.5,4) rectangle (10,-3);
 \clip(-2.84,-1.3) rectangle (9.04,3.58);
 \node (zero) [draw, circle, minimum size=1cm] at (-2,1cm) {$0$};
 \node (one) [draw, circle, minimum size=1cm] at (0,1cm) {$1$};
 \node (two) [draw, circle, minimum size=1cm] at (2,1cm) {$2$};
 \node (enminusone) [draw, circle, minimum size=1cm] at (4,1cm) {$n-1$};
 \node (en) [draw, circle, minimum size=1cm] at (6,1cm) {$n$};
 \node (enplusone) [draw, circle, minimum size=1cm] at (8,1cm) {$n+1$};

 \draw [->] (zero) .. controls +(0.5,1.5) and +(-0.5,1.5) .. node [midway, above] {$\lambda_0$} (one);
 \draw [->] (one) .. controls +(0.5,1.5) and +(-0.5,1.5) .. node [midway, above] {$\lambda_1$} (two);
 \draw [->, very thick, dashed] (two) .. controls +(0.5,1.5) and +(-0.5,1.5) .. (enminusone);
 \draw [->] (enminusone) .. controls +(0.5,1.5) and +(-0.5,1.5) .. node [midway, above] {$\lambda_{n-1}$} (en);
 \draw [->] (en) .. controls +(0.5,1.5) and +(-0.5,1.5) .. node [midway, above] {$\lambda_n$} (enplusone);

 \draw [->] (enplusone) .. controls +(-0.5,-1.5) and +(0.5,-1.5) .. node [midway, below] {$\mu_4$} (en);
 \draw [->] (en) .. controls +(-0.5,-1.5) and +(0.5,-1.5) .. node [midway, below] {$\mu_3$} (enminusone);
 \draw [->, very thick, dashed] (enminusone) .. controls +(-0.5,-1.5) and +(0.5,-1.5) .. (two);
 \draw [->] (two) .. controls +(-0.5,-1.5) and +(0.5,-1.5) .. node [midway, below] {$\mu_2$} (one);
 \draw [->] (one) .. controls +(-0.5,-1.5) and +(0.5,-1.5) .. node [midway, below] {$\mu_0$} (zero);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Uh. Was the `\mu` supposed to be like that?

Comment: I think it made about as much sense as what was in the original post. I'm not sure what the intent of mu is in this graphic, once I know more I can revise the answer (or the OP can make those modifications).

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is needlessly complicated. Unless there is a reason behind those positions with decimals, and depending on what you need to do with this graph, you can do this with a `\foreach` and some `if` statements.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
    circ/.style={draw, circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=8mm, font=\scriptsize},
    triangle/.tip={Computer Modern Rightarrow[open,angle=120:3pt]}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle]

\foreach \text [count=\xi starting from 0, remember=\text as \lastt (initially 0)] in {0,1,2,n-1,n,n+1}{
    \node[circ] (\text) at (\xi,0) {\text};
    \ifnum\xi=3
        \draw[line width=.5mm, dashed] (2.north) arc (180:0:.5);
        \draw[line width=.5mm, dashed] (2.south) arc (180:360:.5);
        \draw[->] (\lastt.north) arc (180:0:.5);
        \draw[<-] (\lastt.south) arc (180:360:.5);
    \else
        \draw[->] (\lastt.north) arc (180:0:.5) node[above, font=\tiny, midway] {$\lambda_\lastt$};
    \ifnum\xi=2
        \draw[<-] (\lastt.south) arc (180:360:.5) node[below, font=\tiny, midway] {$\xi_\mu$};
    \else
    \ifnum\xi=0
        \draw[<-] (\lastt.south) arc (180:360:.5) node[below, font=\tiny, midway] {$\mu_\lastt$};
    \else
    \ifnum\xi>3       
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xy{\xi-1}
        \draw[<-] (\lastt.south) arc (180:360:.5) node[below, font=\tiny, midway] {$\xy_\mu$};
    \else
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
    \fi
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using

- the `chains` library for placing and joining the nodes;
- the `quotes` library for creating the labels above and below the arrows;
- the `arrows.meta` and `bending` libraries for some nicer arrows.

This allows you to specify the code much more concisely. A single `\foreach` loop is used to avoid adding nodes to the chain repeatedly. 4 variables are used in the loop:

- the first (`\i`) specifies the content of the main, circular node;
- the second (`\j`) specifies any special attributes of the arrows (e.g. `dashed`) but is empty in most cases;
- the third (`\k`) specifies the label to go above the top arrow;
- the fourth (`\l`) the label to go below the bottom arrow.

`every on chain` is used to style the main nodes on the `chain`. `my join` holds style attributes we want to use for both the arrows above and below the nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,arrows.meta,quotes,bending}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      every on chain/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=30pt},
      my join/.style={looseness=1.75, font=\scriptsize, >={Stealth[bend]}},
      start chain=main going right,
      node distance=.5,
    ]
    \foreach \i/\j/\k/\l in {0, 1//{$\lambda_0$}/{$\mu_0$}, 2//{$\lambda_1$}/{$\mu_2$}, n-1/dashed//, n//{$\lambda_{n-1}$}/{$\mu_3$}, n+1//{$\lambda_n$}/{$\mu_4$}}
    \node [on chain, join=by {\j, <-, out=-86.5, in=-93.5, my join, "\l"'}, join=by {"\k", \j, ->, out=86.5, in=93.5, my join}] {\i};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It would be possible to further automatise this by creating the content of the labels from an argument specifying just the unique content of each one, but this seemed to me to reduce readability for little gain. (It wouldn't save much typing in this case.)

[image: chained nodes in a loop]

## Enhanced (or otherwise)

In case colour is an option and to your taste, here's an enhanced version. The three colours are defined outside the picture so that they are easy to customise as required.

[image: colours]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,arrows.meta,quotes,bending,shadows}
\begin{document}
  \colorlet{nodecol}{blue!75!green!75!black}
  \colorlet{goingrightcol}{green!75!black}
  \colorlet{goingleftcol}{red!75!black}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      every on chain/.style={circle, draw, nodecol, thick, minimum size=30pt, text height=1ex, inner color=white, outer color=nodecol!10, circular drop shadow},
      my join/.style={looseness=1.75, semithick, font=\footnotesize, >={Stealth[bend]}},
      start chain=main going right,
      node distance=.5,
    ]
    \foreach \i/\j/\k/\l in {0, 1//{$\lambda_0$}/{$\mu_0$}, 2//{$\lambda_1$}/{$\mu_2$}, n-1/dashed//, n//{$\lambda_{n-1}$}/{$\mu_3$}, n+1//{$\lambda_n$}/{$\mu_4$}}
    \node [on chain, join=by {\j, <-, goingleftcol, out=-86.5, in=-93.5, my join, "\l"'}, join=by {"\k", goingrightcol, \j, ->, out=86.5, in=93.5, my join}] {\i};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```